# Convert ByteArrayInputStream to File without saving to Disk

Tags: java, grails, groovy, stripe-payments

This question concerns file handling using Java/Groovy/Grails. I am still new to these technologies, so bear with me.

I am uploading a file to Stripe after receiving the file from a user submitted POST request from the client side. I don't want to save it to the disk if it can be avoided.

I receive the file and parse into an array of bytes.

```
List<MultipartFile> files = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getMultiFileMap().collect {
                it.value
            }.flatten()
            try {
                if (files.size > 0) {
                    // parse file and get byte array input stream
                    MultipartFile file = files.first()
                    String fileName = file.originalFilename
                    byte[] bytes = file.inputStream.getBytes()
                    callStripeFileService(bytes)
            }
```

This byte array is passed to a service which makes the call to Stripe as indicated in [their docs](https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload).

```
    callStripeFileService(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
        String tempFilePath = 
             "src/main/resources/tmp/${fileName}"
        IOUtils.copy(bais, new FileOutputStream(tempFilePath))

        FileCreateParams params = FileCreateParams.builder()
            .setFile(new java.io.File(tempFilePath))
            .setPurpose(FileCreateParams.Purpose.RECEIPT)      
            .build()

        File upload = File.create(params)
    }
```

This is working just fine, but I dislike writing the file to disk only to have to remove it eventually. I also suspect that there must be performance implications to writing to disk.

I would love to just pass a stream to Stripe, but the `.setFile()` method only accepts a File or FileInputStream.

Is there any way to create a valid Java File object without saving anything to disk?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950910/bytearrayinputstream-to-fileinputstream-without-writing-the-file-to-hard-drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; a `java.io.File` is a File, hence the name. No such thing as a virtual file-like thing capturable as a `File` object - `java.io.File` is a very thin wrapper, it has one field, and that is the path, that's all it is. All methods on it, and things like `new FileInputStream(...)` just read the path from that `File` object and do all the work itself, hence making it impossible. Well designed java APIs do not use File; they use, for example, `InputStream`. If the stripe API only allows `File`, then it's badly designed API. The fix would be to send a pull request to the repo with a fix for it.

Presumably, the authors messed up; that variant that takes a `FileInputStream` is an error, and it should have taken an `InputStream` instead. I'll go on record with it, why not: A method whose parameter type is `FileInputStream` is broken. Not broken in the sense that 'tests can catch it', but as broken as a method that adds 2 numbers together named 'subtract'.

TL;DR: Not possible.

Comment: I share your frustration that the method doesn't accept an input stream. I'm sure they have their reasons... Nevertheless you've given me my answer. Thank you

Comment: Hey rzwitserloot, due to your suggestion the library now supports an InputSteam as an argument for setFile(). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can have the user upload the file directly to Stripe so you don't have to worry about it: https://jsfiddle.net/thorstripe/bdm3j2rn/

Apparently I need to include code since there's a jsfiddle link:

```
console.log("Go read the jsfiddle kthx");
```

Comment: Nice example and good suggestion, but other work needs to be done at the controller level with the byte array so this won't work for me.